# AS3: Single Key Press Only

Tags: actionscript-3, keypress

I'm trying to create a platform game and I have the run, jump and double jump working. Now my problem is I want the player to press the jump button and the hero to jump only once instead of continuously jumping. If I hold the up button it will keep jumping which i do not want, i just want it to perform the jump once even if the key is still held down. I want the same for the double jump, how can i do this.

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;

    public class Player extends MovieClip
    {
        //Player run speed setting
        var RunSpeed:Number = 8;
        //Player key presses
        var RightKeyPress:Boolean = false;
        var LeftKeyPress:Boolean = false;
        var UpKeyPress:Boolean = false;
        //Jump variables
        var Gravity:Number = 1.5;
        var JumpPower:Number = 0;
        var CanJump:Boolean = false;
        var DoubleJump:Boolean = false;

        public function Player()
        {
            // constructor code
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,KeyPressed);
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,Update);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,KeyReleased);
        }

        function KeyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent)
        {
            //When Key is Down
            if (event.keyCode == 39)
            {
                RightKeyPress = true;
            }

            if (event.keyCode == 37)
            {
                LeftKeyPress = true;
            }

            if (event.keyCode == 38)
            {
                UpKeyPress = true

            }
        }

        function Update(event:Event)
        {
            //Adding gravity to the game world
            JumpPower +=  Gravity;
            //if player is more than 300 on the y-axis
            if (this.y > 300)
            {
                //Player stays on the ground and can jump
                JumpPower = 0;
                CanJump = true;
                DoubleJump = false;
            }

            //If player is on floor and right key is pressed then run right
            if ((RightKeyPress && CanJump))
            {
                x +=  RunSpeed;
                gotoAndStop('Run');
                scaleX = 1;
            }
            else if ((LeftKeyPress && CanJump))
            {
                //Otherwise if on floor and left key is pressed run left
                x -=  RunSpeed;
                gotoAndStop('Run');
                scaleX = -1;
            }
            else if ((UpKeyPress && CanJump))
            {
                //Otherwise if on floor and up key is pressed then jump
                JumpPower = -15;
                CanJump = false;
                gotoAndStop('Jump');
                DoubleJump = true;
            }

            //If on floor and right and up key are pressed then jump
            if ((RightKeyPress && UpKeyPress && CanJump))
            {
                JumpPower = -15;
                CanJump = false;
                gotoAndStop('Jump');
                DoubleJump = true;
            }

            //If on floor and left and up key are pressed then jump
            if ((LeftKeyPress && UpKeyPress && CanJump))
            {
                JumpPower = -15;
                CanJump = false;
                gotoAndStop('Jump');
                DoubleJump = true;
            }

            //If jumped and right key is pressed then move right
            if ((RightKeyPress && CanJump == false))
            {
                x +=  RunSpeed;
                scaleX = 1;
            }
            else if ((LeftKeyPress && CanJump == false))
            {
                //Otherwise if jumped and left key is pressed then move left
                x -=  RunSpeed;
                scaleX = -1;
            }

            //If in air and able to doublejump and pressed up key, then double jump
            if (UpKeyPress && DoubleJump && JumpPower > -2)
            {
                JumpPower = -13;
                DoubleJump = false;
                gotoAndStop('DoubleJump');
            }

            //If on floor and no key is presses stay idle
            if ((!RightKeyPress && !LeftKeyPress && CanJump))
            {
                gotoAndStop('Idle');
            }

            this.y +=  JumpPower;
        }

        function KeyReleased(event:KeyboardEvent)
        {
            if (event.keyCode == 39)
            {
                event.keyCode = 0;
                RightKeyPress = false;
            }

            if (event.keyCode == 37)
            {
                event.keyCode = 0;
                LeftKeyPress = false;
            }

            if (event.keyCode == 38)
            {
                event.keyCode = 0;
                UpKeyPress = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting a break point in where the double jump occurs?  It looks to me like the logic with the booleans should work out correctly but you must be ending up in that block repeatedly for some reason?  Try tracing out the booleans at key points in the Update function.

Comment: @shaunhusain: Break point? I'm kinda new to AS3 so i don't know much yet but am learning fast.

Comment: No problem, check this link http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/flash_as3_debugging.html or just google around a bit, seems the second half of that article might be helpful but it's long.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that what is happening is that as soon as your player's y value meets the condition `if (this.y > 300)` you are enabling him to jump again, so as long as the key is held down he jumps because `UpKeyPress && CanJump` are both true.

My guess is that doing something like the following might get you closer yo your answer...

In your Update function:

```
function Update(event:Event)
{
    //Adding gravity to the game world
    JumpPower +=  Gravity;
    //if player is more than 300 on the y-axis
    if (this.y > 300)
    {
        //Player stays on the ground and can jump
        JumpPower = 0;
        // Do not allow another jump until the UpKey is pressed
        //CanJump = true;
        //DoubleJump = false;
    }
    ...
```

Then in your KeyPressed function:

```
function KeyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent)
{
    //When Key is Down
    if (event.keyCode == 39)
    {
        RightKeyPress = true;
    }

    if (event.keyCode == 37)
    {
        LeftKeyPress = true;
    }

    if (event.keyCode == 38)
    {
        UpKeyPress = true
        // Do not allow another jump until the UpKey is pressed
        if (this.y > 300)
        {
            CanJump = true;
            DoubleJump = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I also second shaunhusain's recommendation to set breakpoints and get comfortable with debugging code.

Comment: For future reference, there is a Keyboard class that enumerates some of the keys, so you could replace 38 with Keyboard.UP.